# Cuneiform / Akkadian tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

While BH has considerable depth for [hebrew](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) or [greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), [aramaic](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aramaic) has a bit less and there isn't currently an Akkadian tag. I would like to get a sense about what other users think about the potential for tags like this.

I don't have illusions of grandeur: this isn't a anthropology/archaeology site and the contributions that Akkadian / cuneiform scripts in general will likely be marginal. **After all, there was never any scripture written in cuneiform.** However, the Akkadians were also a Semitic people and the scripture has significant overlap when looked at through linguistic analysis.

My case would simply be: each data point is important, no matter how small. The development of the old testament and later works, especially Aramaic authors/pseudopigraphers like the Wisdom of Solomon or the Book of Esther didn't happen in a vacuum. If we draw the line at cuneiform sources, then it's possible we will be missing out on vital context.

I am just one voice, of course.

Comment: I surmise, myself, that the Book of Job could have been written in cuneiform, then a copy came into the hands of Jethro, the priest in Midian, whereupon Moses acquired it in exile then translated it into Hebrew during the wilderness journey. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 4):

A meta discussion isn't generally needed to add a new tag to an appropriate question. If there are a few questions about the scriptures that relate to Akkadian, then by all means add it. But I doubt that there would be very many of those.

Note that people may bring up resources in Akkadian in *answers*, but that does not mean those *questions* are *about Akkadian*, and so the tag should not be added to them. Tags should only be added based on the content of the question, not what any answers bring to bear on the topic.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I suppose I was imagining a scenario where a question specifically asked for the Akkadian perspective or possible literary influence.